# Get old legend labels in-spite they have been updated in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Consider the following code

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create dataframe
data = np.random.rand(10, 2)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")], names=["lev1", "lev2"]
)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

# Create a figure and plot the dataframe
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
df.plot(ax=axes)

# Update the legend
h, l = axes.get_legend_handles_labels()
print(l)
new_labels = ["this", "that"]
axes.legend(h, new_labels)

# Get the current legend
h, ll = axes.get_legend_handles_labels()
print(ll)
```

I would expect `ll==new_labels` but what I got is `ll==l`. However, the legend shown in the plot
is `new_labels`.

Why I don't get the expected result (i.e. `ll==new_labels`)? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the plot you have "this" and "that" as what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, I know. But when I call `h, ll = axes.get_legend_handles_labels()` I don't have `ll=["this","that"]`, as I should expect.

Comment: You seem to think `get_legend_handles_labels()` would get the labels of the current legend.  That is not the case.  It checks the artists in the plot, and returns those that have a legend label.

Comment: You can use `[t.get_text() for t in axes.legend_.texts]` to get the texts of the current legend.

Comment: I see. In-fact I thought that ax.legend(handles, new_labels) would overwrite the current handles labels with new_labels but that is not the case, it only overwrite the legend. To do permanently change the labels one should resort to the Artist.set_label() method. Correct?